# C# SQLite query not return

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sqlite

I have a strange proble. I try to run a query on an SQLite table but it not return the content insted it return "System.Byte[]".
This code is run the query and should get the "text" rows content:

```
    string q = "SELECT text FROM leiras WHERE(id=" + this.id + ");";
    DataTable dt = s.executeNormalQuery(q);
    DataRow dr = dt.Rows[0];
    string content = dr[0].ToString();
```

This is the s.executeNormalQuery(string query):

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(this.conURL);
        con.Open();
        SQLiteCommand com = new SQLiteCommand(query, con);
        SQLiteDataReader read = com.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Load(read);
        read.Close();
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
    }

    return dt;
```

And the "text" cell in the table is containing

```
cg0ovnP0w6XyBKxLQq6XaZpxAPw/lHlSx/fRjZSdmuU=
```

as blob.

Comment: It's returning a `byte[]` because the field is stored as a blob. To convert that, you'd have to know what the content is (e.g. XML).

Comment: You can use System.Text.Encoding class to convert from byte array to string depending on what encoding (UTF8, ASCII...) you're using.

Comment: I tryed to foreach it but it still print "System.Byte[]". I don't know what is the original encoding for the text i only know the text is BASE64 encoded and encrypted using AES. The content is "cg0ovnP0w6XyBKxLQq6XaZpxAPw/lHlSx/fRjZSdmuU="

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks i've found it:

```
    byte[] cont = (byte[]) dr[0];
    string decodedString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(cont);
    Console.WriteLine(decodedString);
```

First cast DataRow 0 to byte[] then encode to UTF-8.